# Error starting up postgresql in 12.10

Tags: 12.10, postgresql

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpq5 postgresql-9.1 postgresql-client-9.1 postgresql-client-common postgresql-common
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/3,389 kB of archives.
After this operation, 15.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpq5.
(Reading database ... 58862 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libpq5 (from .../libpq5_9.1.9-0ubuntu12.10_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package postgresql-client-common.
Unpacking postgresql-client-common (from .../postgresql-client-common_136_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package postgresql-client-9.1.
Unpacking postgresql-client-9.1 (from .../postgresql-client-9.1_9.1.9-0ubuntu12.10_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package postgresql-common.
Unpacking postgresql-common (from .../postgresql-common_136_all.deb) ...
Adding 'diversion of /usr/bin/pg_config to /usr/bin/pg_config.libpq-dev by postgresql-common'
Selecting previously unselected package postgresql-9.1.
Unpacking postgresql-9.1 (from .../postgresql-9.1_9.1.9-0ubuntu12.10_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Setting up libpq5 (9.1.9-0ubuntu12.10) ...
Setting up postgresql-client-common (136) ...
Setting up postgresql-client-9.1 (9.1.9-0ubuntu12.10) ...
Setting up postgresql-common (136) ...
Building PostgreSQL dictionaries from installed myspell/hunspell packages...
 * No PostgreSQL clusters exist; see "man pg_createcluster"
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Setting up postgresql-9.1 (9.1.9-0ubuntu12.10) ...
Creating new cluster (configuration: /etc/postgresql/9.1/main, data: /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main)...
Moving configuration file /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf to /etc/postgresql/9.1/main...
Moving configuration file /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf to /etc/postgresql/9.1/main...
Moving configuration file /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_ident.conf to /etc/postgresql/9.1/main...
Configuring postgresql.conf to use port 5432...
update-alternatives: using /usr/share/postgresql/9.1/man/man1/postmaster.1.gz to provide /usr/share/man/man1/postmaster.1.gz (postmaster.1.gz) in auto mode
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.1 database server                                                                                              * Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 215.
The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output.
                                                                                                                                [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing postgresql-9.1 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Errors were encountered while processing:
 postgresql-9.1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here's the output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux $hostname 3.5.0-36-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 19 15:10:49 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

It's an Amazon AWS EC2 server - `m1.small`.

From a look through `/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster` (a perl script), it's trying to read `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_ctl.conf` to find the log directory and it's somehow getting an invalid value. I don't understand why that would be a problem with a fresh installation.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Odd. When you say "fresh installation" do you mean a new EC2 instance from a clean AMI? Or just a "fresh" PostgreSQL? Any chance you installed it before then removed it without `--purge`, or just didn't remove `postgresql-common` (the Ubuntu wrapper for PostgreSQL)?

Comment: Yep, it was a new EC2 instance with a fresh AMI. I made sure that postgresql-common and all other postgres packages weren't present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simple in the end: postgresql did not have read permissions on its own logs due to an administrative mistake.

This line of code in `pg_ctlcluster` is responsible for setting `$logsize`:

```
$logsize = (stat $info{'logfile'})[7];
```

What threw me off so much was that there's a line just above with:

```
$logsize = 0;
```

So, not understanding the semantics of variables in Perl (and I still don't), I assumed that something much weirder was going on with an error message like `Use of uninitialized value`.

Making `postgres` the owner of its log directory and files did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same error today after updating a development server of ours. I tried many things including adding prints to the `pg_ctlcluster` script to trace what was going on (`$logsize` ends up being set to an unitialized value and in my case the socket itself was never created) as well as complete purge/reinstalls and couldn't get anything to work.

I compared permissions against a production server with the same OS (12.04 LTS in my case) and `/var/run/postgres` as well as `lib` and other directories all matched so couldn't see anything immediate there. Likewise the logfile as specified by `pg_ctlcluster` was owned by postgres and also looked ok.

At a loss I tried setting the log file to a directory I knew would definitely be writeable and accessible, namely `/tmp` by amending the `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_ctl.conf` file thus:

```
# Automatic pg_ctl configuration
# This configuration file contains cluster specific options to be passed to
# pg_ctl(1).

pg_ctl_options = '-l /tmp/pg.log'
```

Postgres was then able to start, I was able to connect and create roles and the configuration was able to pass. I am unsure as yet what is causing this - I gather it's permission related *somehow*. Am just glad to finally be able to carry on - I just needed to do a few tests and was only expecting to spend an hour on it! If I find out what on earth was the cause I will update - I've seen only a few references (a Google search came up with ~6 results *total* for the particular `$logsize` error) to this between Debian, Ubuntu and Linux Mint. It strikes me as odd though that more people haven't encountered this - making me think it's something rather specific and rare.

*edit* possibly related I also had difficulty in getting solr to work earlier. it was also related to a log file not being wrote to. Checking that it was using a symlink to point to the log directory - this resolved just fine but for some reason `service` could not start it. I removed the symlink, created a `log` folder within `/var/lib/tomcat6` and lo-and-behold tomcat could start. I'm wondering if somehow it's related to the log file being specified by a symlink and it being unable to follow it for some reason.